# VPN won't allow access to host machine

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have a local machine (Win7) which I am attempting to connect via VPN to my work machine (Also Win7)

My work machine is behind a firewall in which I have punched a suitable hole.

To a point this appears to be working pretty well.

I have successfully pinged one of our servers (Win2003) at work and have performed a git fetch and git pull against it.

I have likewise been able ping a colleagues machine (Win7)

However, I do not appear to be able to converse with the machine to which I Am actually connecting.

I Cannot ping, not navigate the file system via explorer. It's like the machine is denying it's own existence, Although I am very definitly connecting to my work machine in order to establish the initial connection.

Can someone suggest why I cannot communicate directly with my work machine?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a VPN connection, your machine is actually on the network that you have VPN'd in and that's why you cannot connect to it with your local LAN computer.

The Cisco VPN Client has a "Local LAN Access" option you may have to select.  I'm not sure if the built in Windows VPN Client has a similar option, but I'd imagine so.  Might want to check, depending on what VPN client you are using for a similar option.